# Why is p.summary() causing my script crash when running pyprocessmacro (I use model 1 and 4)

Tags: python, process, statistics

I'm using pyprocessmacro to run mediation analysis, but an issue has occured.
When running p.summary() the script crashes.

I use input textfields to get the variables (from PySimpleGUI).

In my script, I run

```
from PyProcessMacro import Process

iv=valMediation['iv']
dv=valMediation['dv']
m1=valMediation['m']
m_list=[m1]

#Output included variables for control:
print('IV: ' + iv)
print('M: ' + m1)
print('DV: ' + dv)
print('M_list: ' + m_list)

Output dataframe for control:
print(data)
                                       
p = Process(data=data, model=4, x=iv, y=dv, m=m_list)
print('Full summary: ')
p.summary()
```

My output is like this:

```
IV: q0044 
M: q0068 
DV: q0046 
M_list: ['q0068']

     q0044  q0068  q0046 0        2      1      5 1        2      1      5 2        2      1      5 3        3      1      5 4        3      1 
4 ..     ...    ...    ... 201      2      1      4 202      2      1 
5 203      1      1      3 204      3      2      4 205      2      4 
4

[206 rows x 3 columns] 

C:\Users\ChristianOttoRuge\Telia Sky\Christian\CORals\Scripts\CORals-Analytics\Corals-Analytics_3.9.9\3.9.9_venv\lib\site-packages\pyprocessmacro\utils.py:33:
DeprecationWarning: the `interpolation=` argument to percentile was renamed to `method=`, which has additional options. 
Users of the modes 'nearest', 'lower', 'higher', or 'midpoint' are encouraged to review the method they. (Deprecated NumPy 1.22)   
llci = np.percentile(samples, plow * 100, interpolation="lower")

C:\Users\ChristianOttoRuge\Telia Sky\Christian\CORals\Scripts\CORals-Analytics\Corals-Analytics_3.9.9\3.9.9_venv\lib\site-packages\pyprocessmacro\utils.py:34:
DeprecationWarning: the `interpolation=` argument to percentile was renamed to `method=`, which has additional options. 
Users of the modes 'nearest', 'lower', 'higher', or 'midpoint' are encouraged to review the method they. (Deprecated NumPy 1.22)   
ulci = np.percentile(samples, phigh * 100, interpolation="higher") 

Process successfully initialized. 
Based on the Process Macro by Andrew F. Hayes, Ph.D. (www.afhayes.com)

****************************** SPECIFICATION ****************************

Model = 4

Variables:
    Cons = Cons
    x = q0044
    y = q0046
    m1 = q0068

Sample size: 206

Bootstrapping information for indirect effects: Final number of
bootstrap samples: 5000 Number of samples discarded due to convergence
issues: 0 

Full summary:
```

As you can see it breaks when reaching

```
p.summary()
```

It looks like there's something wrong with p, but all variables are checked and validated.

In the output it could look like the variables are not strings, since quotation marks are missing in the output, but I have tried adding quotationmarks to the variables:

```
dv = "'" + dv + "'"
```

without sucsess. This even stops the process earlier.

I've also checked for empty, or non-numerical values in the dataframe, but it looks fine.

If someone can help me out here I'd be extremely greatful!!

Kind regards

Comment: if `dv` is a integer or float then you have to use `str()` to convert it to string. `dv = "'" + str(dv) + "'"` or using string formatting `dv = "'{}'".format(dv)` or f-string `dv = f'"{dv}"'`

Comment: maybe you have to use `print( p.summary() )` to see summary.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out, @furas! I really appreciate it! My variables are strings already. Forcing a new convert to string thise ways stops the process at an earlier stage, when running 'p = Process(data=data, model=4, x=iv, y=dv, m=m_list)'. Printing the summary: 'print( p.summary() )' doesn't solve it either. The scripts still crashes and no output is given :(

Comment: your message show only `DeprecationWarning` - and  warnings are NOT errors but only messages that in next version code may not work, and author of this code should modify it. You can use module `warnings` to hide these warnings - and then you will see what you really get. If it doesn't show any errors then you may only ask author of this module, or you can get source code (path to file you should have in: `PyProcessMacro.__file__`) and try to debug it - you could add `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what it has in variables.

Comment: I wanted to suggest to see source code on GitHub and send problem on GitHub as issue but I see you alread send it [p.summary() makes the script crash.. · Issue #22 · QuentinAndre/pyprocessmacro](https://github.com/QuentinAndre/pyprocessmacro/issues/22)

Comment: here is source code for [summary](https://github.com/QuentinAndre/pyprocessmacro/blob/master/pyprocessmacro/process.py#L1348) and you can see how it works and what variables it uses - so you can check these variables before running `p.summary()` - `print()`, `print( type(...) )`, `print( dir(...) )`, `print( len(...) )`, etc

Comment: Thank you so much, @furas!! I've done quite some new debugging and testing, with no result. On GitHub I can see that my version (1.0.11) was released in oct '21, so I figure there might be a compatibility issue with other updated packages that I use, and I've sort of given up! I found an other package, pingouin, which seems to be doing the actions I need in a very simple way, so I'll just use that for my project instead.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading pyprocessmacro did the job!

```
pip install pyprocessmacro==1.0.12
```

Thanks a lot to [@QuentinAndre at GitHub](https://github.com/QuentinAndre/pyprocessmacro/issues/22) for reaching out with the solution.